# increase the size of the graphics window

Tags: pgfplots

To better see certain details, I would like to be able to enlarge the size of the graphic window: if I increase the domain (and the values ​​of max y), the size remains the same, the curve being more packed.
But I can't find the settings that allow this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                xlabel = {temps $t$ } ,
                ylabel = {nombre de noyaux $N$},
                axis line style={->},
                xmin = 0, xmax = 2000,
                ymin = 0, ymax =20,
                xtick=\empty,
                extra x ticks={346.5,693,1039.5}, extra x tick labels={$t_{1/2}$, $2t_{1/2}$, $3t_{1/2}$},
                ytick={16}, yticklabels={$N_0$},
                extra y ticks = {2,4,8}, extra y tick labels={$\frac{N_0}{8}$,$\frac{N_0}{4}$,$\frac{N_0}{2}$}]
            % Tracé point à point
            \addplot [smooth, thick, red] expression[domain=0:2000] {16*exp(-x/500))};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is sufficient to write; '\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]' ?

Comment: I hadn't thought of it but it's mainly the size in x that interests me and the use of `[xscale=1.5] distorts everything

Comment: With width? section 4.10.1 Common Scaling Options in the doc pgflots

Comment: it's better thanks